# How to fix a ChunkLoadError for a Funnel chart with React Fusion Charts?

Tags: reactjs, fusioncharts

I am trying to render a [Funnel Chart](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/funnel) from Fusion Charts using the following component in React (which is rendered through several parent components):

```jsx
import React, { Component } from "react";

import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import ReactFusioncharts from "react-fusioncharts";

// Resolves charts dependency
charts(FusionCharts);

const dataSource = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Website visits",
    subcaption: "Purchase - Conversion analysis for last year",
    decimals: "1",
    showvalues: "1",
    plottooltext: "$label: <b>$dataValue</b>",
    plotfillalpha: "70",
    theme: "fusion",
    streamlineddata: "0"
  },
  data: [
    {
      label: "Website Visits",
      value: "17362"
    },
    {
      label: "Downloads",
      value: "8039"
    },
    {
      label: "Checked Pricing",
      value: "5509"
    },
    {
      label: "Asked for Quotation",
      value: "3962"
    },
    {
      label: "Purchased",
      value: "2397"
    }
  ]
};

export default class FunnelChart extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactFusioncharts
        type="funnel"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        dataFormat="JSON"
        dataSource={dataSource}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

On page load, I get this error in the browser console:

```console
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
4.js:35464 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 5 failed.
(missing: http://localhost:8000/dashboards/fusioncharts.widgets.js)
    at Function.a.e (4.js:35464)
    at d (4.js:35464)
    at Function.<anonymous> (4.js:35464)
    at i (4.js:35464)
    at o (4.js:35464)
    at f (4.js:35464)
    at e.t.chartType (4.js:35464)
    at new e (4.js:35464)
    at new h (4.js:35464)
    at ReactFC.renderChart (4.js:122201)
    at 4.js:35464
```

I tried adding the line `import "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widgets";`, and it removed the error but chart didn't display. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the import statements with the below code, and reload the app clearing the browser cache

```
import FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import Widgets from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.widget';
import FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
import ReactFC from 'react-fusioncharts';

ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Widgets, FusionTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution for the above problem is that you are importing the chart from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts" instead of the import chart from "fusion-charts/fusion-charts. widgets".
the reason for the above is that funnel is exported from "fusion-charts/fusion charts. widgets" (you can check this, just go to node_modules and find fusion-charts in that find widgets folder) and not from the "fusion-charts/fusion-charts.charts". For Info you can check Fusion documentation.